# Getting "TypeError: Cannot convert a symbolic Keras input/output to a numpy array"

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, numpy-ndarray

I don't know how to fix anything. But it error straight #Attention Layer. I am using Tensorflow v.2.6 and Keras v.2.6.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Layer
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K


class AttentionLayer(Layer):
    """
    This class implements Bahdanau attention (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.0473.pdf).
    There are three sets of weights introduced W_a, U_a, and V_a
     """

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AttentionLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert isinstance(input_shape, list)
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.

        self.W_a = self.add_weight(name='W_a',
                                   shape=tf.TensorShape((input_shape[0][2], input_shape[0][2])),
                                   initializer='uniform',
                                   trainable=True)
        self.U_a = self.add_weight(name='U_a',
                                   shape=tf.TensorShape((input_shape[1][2], input_shape[0][2])),
                                   initializer='uniform',
                                   trainable=True)
        self.V_a = self.add_weight(name='V_a',
                                   shape=tf.TensorShape((input_shape[0][2], 1)),
                                   initializer='uniform',
                                   trainable=True)

        super(AttentionLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

    def call(self, inputs, verbose=False):
        """
        inputs: [encoder_output_sequence, decoder_output_sequence]
        """
        assert type(inputs) == list
        encoder_out_seq, decoder_out_seq = inputs
        if verbose:
            print('encoder_out_seq>', encoder_out_seq.shape)
            print('decoder_out_seq>', decoder_out_seq.shape)

        def energy_step(inputs, states):
            """ Step function for computing energy for a single decoder state
            inputs: (batchsize * 1 * de_in_dim)
            states: (batchsize * 1 * de_latent_dim)
            """

            assert_msg = "States must be an iterable. Got {} of type {}".format(states, type(states))
            assert isinstance(states, list) or isinstance(states, tuple), assert_msg

            """ Some parameters required for shaping tensors"""
            en_seq_len, en_hidden = encoder_out_seq.shape[1], encoder_out_seq.shape[2]
            de_hidden = inputs.shape[-1]

            """ Computing S.Wa where S=[s0, s1, ..., si]"""
            # <= batch size * en_seq_len * latent_dim
            W_a_dot_s = K.dot(encoder_out_seq, self.W_a)

            """ Computing hj.Ua """
            U_a_dot_h = K.expand_dims(K.dot(inputs, self.U_a), 1)  # <= batch_size, 1, latent_dim
            if verbose:
                print('Ua.h>', U_a_dot_h.shape)

            """ tanh(S.Wa + hj.Ua) """
            # <= batch_size*en_seq_len, latent_dim
            Ws_plus_Uh = K.tanh(W_a_dot_s + U_a_dot_h)
            if verbose:
                print('Ws+Uh>', Ws_plus_Uh.shape)

            """ softmax(va.tanh(S.Wa + hj.Ua)) """
            # <= batch_size, en_seq_len
            e_i = K.squeeze(K.dot(Ws_plus_Uh, self.V_a), axis=-1)
            # <= batch_size, en_seq_len
            e_i = K.softmax(e_i)

            if verbose:
                print('ei>', e_i.shape)

            return e_i, [e_i]

        def context_step(inputs, states):
            """ Step function for computing ci using ei """

            assert_msg = "States must be an iterable. Got {} of type {}".format(states, type(states))
            assert isinstance(states, list) or isinstance(states, tuple), assert_msg

            # <= batch_size, hidden_size
            c_i = K.sum(encoder_out_seq * K.expand_dims(inputs, -1), axis=1)
            if verbose:
                print('ci>', c_i.shape)
            return c_i, [c_i]

        fake_state_c = K.sum(encoder_out_seq, axis=1)
        fake_state_e = K.sum(encoder_out_seq, axis=2)  # <= (batch_size, enc_seq_len, latent_dim

        """ Computing energy outputs """
        # e_outputs => (batch_size, de_seq_len, en_seq_len)
        last_out, e_outputs, _ = K.rnn(
            energy_step, decoder_out_seq, [fake_state_e],
        )

        """ Computing context vectors """
        last_out, c_outputs, _ = K.rnn(
            context_step, e_outputs, [fake_state_c],
        )

        return c_outputs, e_outputs

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        """ Outputs produced by the layer """
        return [
            tf.TensorShape((input_shape[1][0], input_shape[1][1], input_shape[1][2])),
            tf.TensorShape((input_shape[1][0], input_shape[1][1], input_shape[0][1]))
        ]
```

and

```
from keras import backend as K 
K.clear_session() 
latent_dim = 500 

# Encoder 
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(max_len_text,)) 
enc_emb = Embedding(x_voc_size, latent_dim,trainable=True)(encoder_inputs) 

#LSTM 1 
encoder_lstm1 = LSTM(latent_dim,return_sequences=True,return_state=True,dropout=0.5) 
encoder_output1, state_h1, state_c1 = encoder_lstm1(enc_emb) 
#layer1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)
#dropout_output1, state_h2, state_c2 = layer2(encoder_output2)

#LSTM 2 
encoder_lstm2 = LSTM(latent_dim,return_sequences=True,return_state=True,dropout=0.5) 
encoder_output2, state_h2, state_c2 = encoder_lstm2(encoder_output1)
#layer2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)
#dropout_output2, state_h2, state_c2 = layer2(encoder_output2) 

#LSTM 3 
encoder_lstm3=LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True, return_sequences=True,dropout=0.5) 
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c= encoder_lstm3(encoder_output2) 
#layer = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)

# Set up the decoder. 
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,)) 
dec_emb_layer = Embedding(y_voc_size, latent_dim,trainable=True) 
dec_emb = dec_emb_layer(decoder_inputs) 

#LSTM using encoder_states as initial state
decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True) 
decoder_outputs,decoder_fwd_state, decoder_back_state = decoder_lstm(dec_emb,initial_state=[state_h, state_c]) 

#Attention Layer
attn_layer = AttentionLayer(name='attention_layer') 
attn_out, attn_states = attn_layer([encoder_outputs, decoder_outputs]) 

# Concat attention output and decoder LSTM output 
decoder_concat_input = Concatenate(axis=-1, name='concat_layer')([decoder_outputs, attn_out])

#Dense layer
decoder_dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(y_voc_size, activation='softmax')) 
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_concat_input)
```

TypeError: 'KerasTensor' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

TypeError: Cannot convert a symbolic Keras input/output to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a symbolic value to a NumPy call, which is not supported. Or, you may be trying to pass Keras symbolic inputs/outputs to a TF API that does not register dispatching, preventing Keras from automatically converting the API call to a lambda layer in the Functional Model.

Comment: Which line do you get the error on?

Comment: line#Attention Layer

attn_out, attn_states = attn_layer([encoder_outputs, decoder_outputs])

Comment: you mean class AttentionLayer(Layer): right? ,I look at this person https://github.com/thushv89/attention_keras/blob/master/src/layers/attention.py

Comment: There is a lot of stuff that is going on in the original code. Try building up your code using small understandable sections. You are taking on more than you can chew. If someone else knows exactly why the error is appearing, probably they can answer.

Comment: Please try again using the latest tensorflow version > 2.7. You can use this code line to install the upgraded tensorflow version - `!pip install --upgrade tensorflow`